# getting error 404 when trying to get forecast from openweathermap with expo (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, openweathermap

I am writing a weather app exercise with React Native on my PC and on expo site as well (to show others).  I am getting current weather and forecast fro OpenWeatherMap.

https//:api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=38.3647273&lon=-8.5212805&appid=...
https//:api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=38.3647273&lon=-8.5212805&appid=...

Both url requests work on my phone via expo on PC. But I getan "Request failed with status code 404" with the forecast request on expo.  The weather request works.  That is weird.  Any idea why this is happening?:-)

[image: expo]

[image: phone]

Comment: Can you give more information ? The error, the response of the api ?

Comment: the forward slashes for your http requests are missing, likely causing the 404 error. is this intentional?

Comment: The missing forward slashes as typo.  
Here is the expo link.
[link](https://snack.expo.io/@net2tim/aab92e)

Enter a city name in the input filed.